# Code for calculating how many leaves are left unharmed

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, runtime-error, long-integer

Recently I was practicing [this](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/LEAFEAT) problem , where I need to calculate the total number of leaves which are left unharmed by the caterpillars.

And fortunately I did the code pretty fast only to find that it gave `Runtime Error` by the IARCS judge.

Here is the particular test case:

```
762744433 19
96412 40852 19611 563380 236733 559627 750968 413673 300332 65 682403 441221 180068 668364 493413 443706 613246 715846 728157
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    long long n , k;
    std::cin >> n >> k;
    long long caterpillars[k];
    std::vector<long long>v;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        std::cin >> caterpillars[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        for(int j=0;caterpillars[i]*j +1 <= n;j++){
            int temp = caterpillars[i]*j +1;
            v.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    int number = 0;
    long long prev = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        if(v[i] != prev){
            number++;
        }
        prev = v[i];
    }
    std::cout << n - number << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the surprising part is the code gives the accurate answer in my pc , gdb also does the same but there lies the shitty IARCS judge.

Can anyone help me in it?

Comment: `long long caterpillars[k];` is not standard and should not compile.  You should replace it with a `std::vector`.

Comment: who said it wont compile?

Comment: I said should not.  There are compilers that do allow it if you do not have the warnings turned up.  See this ["working"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86d08a258d1ae8f5) and ["non-working"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1654f30c7c6db9f3) examples

Comment: oh ok , bdw changing it to vector does n't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The memory limit specified by the judge is 64 MB. The procedure you are using to solve the question doesn't guarantee that the space consumed will be less than 64 MB. Actually it will exceed the limit in a lot of test cases. Example: 1000000000 1 2.

Most competitive programming website do distinguish between Runtime Error and Memory Limit Exceeded. If IARCS does so too, then there must be some other reason  for the error.